# Bibliography not giving the whole informations

Tags: bibtex

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
    \section*{Whatever}
    \blindtext
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{dafpus}
    \nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

dafpus.bib

```
@book{DK86,
    author = "D.E. Knuth",
    title = "The {\TeX}book"
    publisher = "Addison Wesley",
    year = 1986
}

@article{DK89,
    author = "D.E. Knuth",
    title = "Typesetting Concrete Mathematics",
    journal = "TUGboat"
    volume = 10,
    number = 1,
    pages = "31--36"
    month = apr,
    year = 1989
}
```

It only gives the author, and the title informations. Publisher, year, volume, pages, month, and number didn't appear.

This is my output: [image](https://ibb.co/JxtsfmN)

Btw, i use imgbb instead of imgur. Cz not supported on my country.

Hope you can help my problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't ignore bibtex errors, there is a comma missing after the title in DK86

Comment: Similarly, there is a missing comma after the `journal` and the `pages` field in `DK89`. After a missing comma BibTeX has trouble parsing the rest of the entry and may have to abandon it resulting in missing fields.